# ESLint is reading other configurations

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I have a simple `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "twilio"
  ]
}
```

But when I run my eslint, I get

> The config "standard" was referenced from the config file in
>   "/Users/MyAccount/Projects/my-sample-app/node_modules/cipher-base/.eslintrc".

I even tried to make the eslint to ignore and used the following:

```
➜ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --config .eslintrc --ignore-pattern node_modules/ ./jest.setup.js
```

but it's still giving me the same error. Why is eslint trying to read this other config file?

Comment: Not positive, but does `npm install eslint-config-standard` fix it?

Comment: I don't want to install other configs; that's the plugin for one of my deps, I don't care about that.

Comment: Okay, are you running this from an npm script or manually typing in `./node_modules/.bin/eslint ...` into a terminal?

Comment: Manually typing that in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can run `eslint` with `--debug` flag to see why a config is being loaded. You can also run with `--print-config` flag to see how your config looks like once all of the extends and cascading completes. ESLint by default will cascade configs (as in, it will walk directory structure from the current folder to the top to find all configs) and combines them all for linting. Most likely, one of the parent folders have eslint config that extends standard. `--debug` flag should tell you where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it from an npm script, like this

`"scripts": {"eslint": "eslint --config .eslintrc --ignore-pattern node_modules/ ./jest.setup.js"}` and then running `npm run eslint`

What I think is happening is, when running it from the terminal like `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --config .eslintrc --ignore-pattern node_modules/ ./jest.setup.js`, `eslint` looks for the first `.eslintrc` file it can find relative to it's own location `node_modules/.bin` in this example. When you run it in an npm script, it should look for the first `.eslintrc` file relative to the package.json file.